# Did I install this roof vent correctly?

Tags: roofing, exhaust-vent, shingles, flashing

I’m installing a roof vent to exhaust a new kitchen cooktop. I put a 6” hole in my roof and fit this painted metal vent between the asphalt shingles. I have sealed around the roof penetration l, under the vent flashing along the top and sides, over the vent flashing on the sides under the shingles, and over the two nails I put through at the bottom. I used Henry Wet Patch because it’s already 44F outside and not likely to warm up any time soon.

I feel like I cut away more shingles than I should have on the sides. And on top, the flashing is below two layers of shingle. Is this correct?

[image: roof vent 1]
[image: roof vent 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this looks correct. You're right about cutting away too much shingle, but it looks like you fixed it with sealant.

Comment: Thanks. My first time putting holes in the roof and it’s raining tomorrow. Fingers crossed.